# Does "including" change the plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

When the phrase "including something" is used, will the plural changed?
For example:
Everyone is required to wear shoes.
Everyone, including the staff, is/are required to wear shoes.

Comment: This is a clear parenthetical; parenthetical comments do not force agreement changes. Thus: 'Everyone, including John and Jane, is required to wear shoes.' // 'All staff members, including John, are required to wear shoes.' There are trickier examples, though.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't.

Let's analyse your example:

> Everyone, including the staff, [is/are] required to wear shoes.

"Everyone" is the main bit of detail, and the main clause is *everyone is required*. If you remove *including the staff* from the sentence then you would obviously use "is". Since *including the staff* is somewhat separate to the main clause its purpose is little more than to add detail and so the sentence's syntax should be the same as if it were *Everyone is required to wear shoes*.

TL;DR - Use "is".